# Can someone explain this formula to me. It is a tapered hole

Tags: geometry

I could not figure out how to do a couple of the symbols so I am inserting an image.

I am trying to figure out how to use this formula.  It does involve machining a tapered hole but I am at a loss on how to use it.[picture of formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Aq0R.png)

Transcription of formula: 
$$
\Delta H = 0.1 - \frac{0.025}{\tan \frac{\theta}{2}}.
$$

Here is some more information.

[more information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/220A5.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I've transcribed your formula to MathJax (which we use here for formatting math), because folks don't usually like pictures in questions. Let me know if you think I've transcribed it incorrectly.

Comment: It's a pretty straightforward formula. You input the angle $\theta$ (I don't know what it is exacly, but maybe it's explained in the book) and the outcome is the value $\Delta H$. Which aspect is confusing to you?

Comment: It is not in a book.  This from a blueprint of a part to be made but I am not sure how how to use it.

Comment: And thanks for transcribing it.

Comment: The definition of $\theta$ can be seen in the second picture (written sideways). Is it still confusing?

Comment: I think you need help from a mechanical engineer, not a mathematician.

Answer (score 1):

John.

I assume that this is for some sort of machining process, and I haven't much experience with machining. But let me try to make a guess or two.

If your "tapered" hole had no taper, it'd be a cylinder, right? In that case, we'd say that the angle of taper is $\theta = 0$. If the sides tilted in just a little bit, we might say that the taper was $\theta = 1$ degree. If it looked like a "90 degree) countersink, we might say that the taper was $\theta = 45$ degrees (i.e., the taper is the slope of *one side* of the hole, compared to vertical). I could easily be wrong here: the taper might be the angle between the two opposite sides, so that for a 90-degree countersink, the taper would be $90$ degrees. The use of $\theta/2$ in your formula suggests to me that this latter interpretation might be the correct one, but without more information, I can't say.

Let's suppose that the taper is $\theta = 10$ degrees. Then $\theta/2$ is $5$ degrees, and $\tan \frac{\theta}{2} \approx 0.0875$ (I got this answer using a calculator set to "degrees" mode!)

Then your formula says that 
$$
\Delta H 
= 0.1 - \frac{0.025}{\tan \frac{\theta}{2}} 
\approx 0.1 - \frac{0.025}{0.0875} 
\approx 0.1 - 0.2857 \approx -0.1857
$$
where $\approx$ means "is approximately equal to," because I suspect you don't want more than a few decimal digits of accuracy for machining.

The symbol $\Delta$ is often used to mean "the change in", so this seems to say that the "change in H" should be $-0.1857$. I don't know what $H$ is in your setup, but this suggests reducing it by a modest amount.

I'm sorry not to be able to be more confident in my answer, but to do so, I'd need a bit more context.

Comment: And now I see (from your added picture) that my second interpretation was correct: $\theta$ is the angle between the two sides, not the angle from one side to the centerline. I can't make sense in your picture of what $\Delta H$ is -- it looks like the thickness of a single line -- but presumably *you* can make sense of that.

Comment: Thanks, I think I can do this now.  What is the symbol of the o with a line threw it called?

Comment: That's called "theta" (rhymes with "hate, uh"). It's the 8th letter in the Greek alphabet. I think that in modern greek it might be pronounced to rhyme with "heat, uh" ... just in case you ever get a Greek mechanic in your shop. :)

Comment: Thanks for all of the help.